# Why wp blog archive page, use index template?

Tags: wordpress, file, templates

I want to modify the template of my blog archive page. I want to modify the template file by following the hierarchy of wordpress files, and not to apply a template manually.

I created a page, then set the blog page in the settings> reading. According to the functioning of the file hierarchy, this should use the file archive.php however it is the file index.php which is loaded. Why ?

My wordpress is blank. I just installed the blank WordPress theme JointsWP.

[image: Wordpress Hierarchy files]

Thanks in advance.
Vince.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the hierarchy more carefully, blog posts link to the index.php, not the archive.php.